# Java formatter going to new line

Tags: java

I am wondering is there any way after it writes to the txt file it goes to the next line ?

```
stdIn2.format("%s", x[i]);
```

like

```
a 
b   
c
```

I have tried `stdIn2.format("%s\n", x[i]);` but it does't work

Comment: you want to write a new line character after writing some text ?

Comment: i mean, in new text file I just created I am doing loop to add x[i] to new text file but I want after adding each string of array x put some thing we did in strings like \n or going to new line

Comment: Are you using windows and viewing the file with notepad.exe?

Comment: yes I am using windows's notepad

Comment: Very interesting. *Now define "doesn't work":* i.e., what does it do, and what did you expect it to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
stdIn2.format("%s%n", x[i]);
```

The `%n` stands for platform-specific line separator in the formatter:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html), and follow the conventions listed in the API.  `println()` will be familiar to you immediately.

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("out.txt"));
out.println(String.format("%s", x[i]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.out.println(String.formtat(...))`. This will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `lineSeparator()` as :

```
     stdIn2.format("%s"+System.lineSeparator(), x[i]);
```

This will append `\r\n` as line separator in `Windows` based environment.

Answer (score 0):

Using notepad.exe is not the best choice.

In Windows a new line is defined by two chars: '\n' and '\r'
In Linux it is only one '\n'
(In MacOs it is only '\r' iirc)

Your programm only outputs a '\n' which won't be recognised as a new line by notepad. Notepad++, which is way better than notepad, will show the result as expected.